# Excel CONCAT expected End of Statement error

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, spreadsheet

I am trying to combine first and last names into one column.  I have this in my VBA:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+CONCAT(a2, " ", b2)" but I get an Expected: End of Statement error.

I have tried adding and removing the spaces after the commas and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried removing the plus sign.

Comment: You need to double up the inner quotes, use `.Formula`, and drop the `+`.

Comment: You have to escape the double quote by adding one more double quote i.e "=+CONCAT(a2, "" "", b2)"